# Как в GDB правильно открыть core dump с другой машины, чтобы были символы?

Tags: linux, gdb, dump, core

Есть файл кор-дампа с другого хоста, нужно посмотреть его локально. Для этого поднят докер с той же ОС и версией проекта, но при загрузке файла GDB не показывает символы. Я так понимаю это из-за разницы адресов.

Как посмотреть кор-дамп с символами на локальной машине?

Comment: ¿А символы действительно были? Также приводите команды, которыми открываете и вывод.

Comment: @user7860670 конечно, символы есть. `gdb (путь_к_исполняемому) (путь_к_корке)`, потом просто `bt`

Comment: LD_LIBRARY_PATH такой же указан? 
символы в сборку включаются еще

Comment: ээ, запустите gdb без аргументов, потом выполните `file <путь к файлу>` и приведите вывод

Comment: @SeniorPomidor LD_LIBRARY_PATH указан такой, чтобы проект запускался, то есть там, где фактически лежат либы. Соответствует ли он тому, что на удалённом хосте я не уверен. Это важно?

Comment: @user7860670 `(gdb) file (project_path) 
Reading symbols from (project_path)...done.`

Comment: Ну вот, символы загружены. Соответственно теперь если загрузить корку, то они будут использованы.

Comment: @user7860670 а как это сделать на зпущенном gdb, не подскажете? Когда пишу `file (путь_к_корке)` gdb выдаёт "No such file or directory", хотя путь к файлу сам дополняется по Tab, естественно он там есть.

Comment: для загрузки корки надо писать `core <путь к корке>`

Comment: @user7860670 то же самое `#1  0x00007f9bf54ac42a in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89 
#2  0x00007f9bf659f4ca in ?? () 
#3  0x00007f9bf663a429 in ?? () 
#4  0x000000000290dd90 in ?? () ...`

Comment: ¿И что, символов вообще нигде не видно? ¿Или только конкретно для этого стека вызовов? Там же могут быть еще фреймы от сторонних библиотек которые без символов. Во всяком случае, проблема не в том, что символы не подгружаются из исполняемого файла.